# How do Install ExpressionEngine on IIS

Tags: ee2, php

I've confirmed the server requirements for the windows server and they match or exceed what is recommended.

I have uploaded the files to a directory on the server and am trying to run the ExpressionEngine installer.

I continue to get a "The page cannot be found" error. This is my first time trying to install on a windows server, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Do I need to add a php.ini file, .htaccess, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What address are you using when you get this error message? Are you trying to navigate to the Control panel or the public site?

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend using an Apache server and not an IIS. You can probably get it running but it will be a big pain in the you-know-what. PHP runs way better on an apache server and I'd recommend going this route instead. Perhaps other people have had better luck, but not me!

Comment: Just in case it helps, we do a lot of EECMS installs on IIS so we posted some tips and tricks here http://www.climbingturn.co.uk/resources/expressionengine-tips-and-tricks Windows uses a web.config file instead of htaccess, we posted an example here http://www.climbingturn.co.uk/resources/expressionengine-tips-and-tricks/how-to-remove-index.php-on-iis

Comment: I'm using the web address plus the path to the folder. (ie. http://webaddress/promotion/admin.php

Comment: I have never had to work with an IIS server. Are the Server requirements that EE needs to run have to be enabled or are the automatically enabled. The hosing provider has said that the server meets the requirements. Wish I could run this on Apache. Unfortunately it's not an option at the moment.

Comment: It appears that I have to have admin access to the server. Is this the case. It's a shared hosting plan which I don't have the full access rights.

Comment: Curious, did you run the installation wizard first?

Comment: Can the hosting provider confirm that php is installed on this hosting plan? Have you tried uploading a simple php file as a test? Unlike apache, php is optional on IIS.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for chiming in. I haven't been able to run the installation wizard. I can't even load a PHP file. I created a test file with a PHP extension and it wouldn't load it. Is it a hosting issue or is there something I can do to get PHP running?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the hosting you have it's hard to tell what the problem is. When you try to navigate to your test PHP file what happens? Do you get an error? I am starting to suspect that PHP may not be installed on this hosting plan. Try creating an empty file with a php extension and just place this code in it <?php phpInfo(); ?> Upload it to your root folder and try to navigate to it. You should see the PHP setup if all is configured properly (Note - this isn't foolproof as phpinfo can be switched off - so it's still best to ask your web hosts whether it's installed)